# How to mirror only tags to codecommit from bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, bitbucket

I have an AWS CodeCommit repo. It has as source a bitbucket repo.
I am following this guide:

https://blog.phamviet.net/mirror-bitbucket-to-aws-codecommit/

Is there a way to mirror the bitbucket repo just if the commit has got a tag?

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/#Before-you-begin:~:text=the%20branch%20names.-,tags,-Defines%20all%20tag Just make a tag specific pipeline that pushes your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Pipeline (using bitbucket and CodePipeline), I resolved creating an ssh key in my bitbucket's repository (>Settings), importing it to a user, on my AWS account, with right permissions (see below), and writing this bitbucket-pipelines.yml file:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  tags:
    '*':
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com" >> ~/.ssh/config
            - echo "User <ssh-user-id>" >> ~/.ssh/config
            - git remote add codecommit ssh://<ssh-repo-uri>
            - git push codecommit ${BITBUCKET_TAG}
            - git push codecommit HEAD:master
```

I commit even HEAD:master because CodeBuild's source comes just from the branch (in this case master) and not from **ALL** git tags.

User's permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:ListRepositoriesForApprovalRuleTemplate",
                "codecommit:CreateApprovalRuleTemplate",
                "codecommit:UpdateApprovalRuleTemplateName",
                "codecommit:GetApprovalRuleTemplate",
                "codecommit:ListApprovalRuleTemplates",
                "codecommit:DeleteApprovalRuleTemplate",
                "codecommit:ListRepositories",
                "codecommit:UpdateApprovalRuleTemplateContent",
                "codecommit:UpdateApprovalRuleTemplateDescription"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:<region>:<account-id>:<codecommit-repo-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```